# How to (unit)test a weakrefence list's memory management function?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, memory-management, garbage-collection, nunit

Excuses for the bad title: if someone can describe it better please do.

I have a `WeakList<T>` class, which "is" basically a `List<WeakReference<T>>` (Though not in the literal sense that it derives from list, but rather it should be completelly transparent for the user).

Now the underlying idea is that "items are ignored if the referenced variable is gone", ie a part of the `WeakList<T>` source is:

```
public class WeakList<T> : IReadOnlyList<T>, IWeakList<T>, IWeakCollection<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>,
    ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable where T : class
{
    private readonly List<WeakReference<T>> _myList;
    public void Add(T item) {
        _myList.Add(new WeakReference<T>(item));
    }
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() {
        foreach (var reference in _myList) {
            T elem;
            if (reference.TryGetTarget(out elem)) {
                yield return elem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am still contemplating if `List` actually makes sense here, weaklist[n] won't be always the same as getting it through iterating to the nth element. - Is there a collection-name for something which does have an order, but no index-based-access?

But besides that point: 
This class also includes a "purge" function, which is aimed at "removing no longer existing references".

```
    public void Purge() {
        for (int i = _myList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            T elem;
            if (!_myList[i].TryGetTarget(out elem)) {
                _myList.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now my question is: how do I test above method in a unit-test (for Nunit)?  How can I setup a list, then make sure some elements are removed, and then call purge and test it, something like:

```
[TestFixture]
public class WeakListTests
{
    [Test]
    public static void PurgeTest() {
        var myList = new WeakList<string>;
        string s1 = "hello world 1";
        string s2 = "hello world 2";
        string s3 = "hello world 3";
        myList.Add(s1);
        myList.Add(s2);
        myList.Add(s3);
        // "clear", force s1 & s2 away. (yet keep a reference so I can test it gets removed)
        myList.Purge();
        Assert.That(myList, Does.Not.Contain(s1));
        Assert.That(myList, Does.Not.Contain(s2));
        Assert.That(myList, Does.Contain(s3));

    }
}
```

The comment describes at what point I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this (see comments):

```
[TestFixture]
public class WeakListTests
{
    [Test]
    public static void PurgeTest()
    {
        var myList = new WeakList<string>();
        // construct strings like this to prevent interning
        string s1 = new string(new[] { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' });
        string s2 = new string(new[] { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '2' });
        // this string can be interned, we don't want it to be collected anyway
        string s3 = "hello world 3";            
        myList.Add(s1);
        myList.Add(s2);
        myList.Add(s3);
        // set to null for that to work even in application built with "Debug"
        // in Release it will work without setting to null
        s1 = null;
        s2 = null;
        // force GC collection
        GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);            
        // now s1 and s2 are away
        myList.Purge();
        // invoke your enumerator
        var left = myList.ToArray();            
        // should contain 1 item and that item should be s3
        Assert.That(left.Length == 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(s3, left[0]);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this "guaranteed to work" by the specs or is it "just working"?

Comment: @paul23 I don't see why it can not work. We have 2 variables that are out of scope (are not used anywhere below in the method), we force immediate garbage collection, they are collected, weak references are not alive any more. But, even IF that for some reason, under some unknown conditions, won't work - your unit test will fail and you will notice. I would understand your concerns if that test would silently pass in case of problems, but that won't happen. If it has passed - 2 weak references are not alive and 1 is alive, just as expected.

Comment: @paul23 and which part of the code worries you? Forced garbage collection?

Comment: yes, is the forcing actually a guarantee or just a suggestion to the garbage collector. (Like how forced inline in C++ works).

Comment: @paul23 yes it is guarantee, however what exactly will be collected is up to collector. Since you are testing memory management - you have no other way anyway. You do not need super strong guarantees in this case, because   in (imaginary) case of misbehavior it makes no harm.